# Show wrong images in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

there! I need your help. I have UIImage inside UICollectionView which lying inside UITableView. When I get data from API at the first time it shows images right, but when I start to scroll down and come back, it shows wrong images. My code looks like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AllPostsOfUserCollectionViewCell

    let post = allPostsOfUserArray[collectionView.tag]
    if post.imageLinks.count != 0 {
        let imageLink = post.imageLinks[indexPath.row]

        if imageLink.imageLink != nil {
            let url = URL(string: imageLink.imageLink!)

            cell.imageOfAnimalInCollectionView.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
            })
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
class UserContent {

var name = ""
var imageLinks = [UserImages]()

init(name: String, imageLinks: [UserImages]?) {        
    self.name = name
    if imageLinks != nil {
        self.imageLinks = imageLinks!
    }
}

init() { }

deinit {
    imageLinks.removeAll()
  }
}


class UserImages {

var imageLink: String?

init(imageLink: String?) {
    self.imageLink = imageLink
}

init() { }

deinit {
    imageLink = ""
   }
 }
```

What I do in UITableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let index = indexPath.row

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! AllPostsOfUserTableViewCell

    cell.collectionView.tag = index

    let post = allPostsOfUserArray[index]
    if post.imageLinks.count == 0 {
        cell.collectionView.isHidden = true
    } else {
        cell.collectionView.isHidden = false
    }

    return cell
}
```

**UPD:** I added **cell.collectionView.reloadData()** to func tableView(cellForRowAt indexPath). Now it works fine.

Comment: In all of your `else` (which you didn't do), you need to remove the image or put a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.imageOfAnimalInCollectionView.image = nil
if post.imageLinks.count != 0 {
    let imageLink = post.imageLinks[indexPath.row]

    if imageLink.imageLink != nil {
        let url = URL(string: imageLink.imageLink!)

        cell.imageOfAnimalInCollectionView.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
        })
    }

}
```

(Not tested, but should work. You can also use `sd_image`'s method to assign an empty url, with a placeholder image to just show the placeholder image. Or just give an empty url string `''` without the placeholder image)

Whenever you scroll, the cells are re-used, and the image assigned to the cell reappears because it is still on the cell.
You have to remove those images by using `else` clause for every `if` where you are assigning an image to the imageView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I still have some troubles. I think, maybe it's because of the wrong model.

Comment: @DmytroRyshchuk great that you found a solution. Nevertheless i think it is a good practice to set the image to nil or a placeholder image.
It will be helpful incase you are dealing with more data

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AllPostsOfUserCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageOfAnimalInCollectionView.image = UIImage(named: "App-Default")
    let post = allPostsOfUserArray[collectionView.tag]
    if post.imageLinks.count != 0 {
        let imageLink = post.imageLinks[indexPath.row]

        if imageLink.imageLink != nil {
            let url = URL(string: imageLink.imageLink!)

            cell.imageOfAnimalInCollectionView.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
            })
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is something like race condition.
You can reference my answer in [similair question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285976/8218581)

You might need to find another module to download image and set to cell manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write else conditions like Below ..

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AllPostsOfUserCollectionViewCell

    let post = allPostsOfUserArray[collectionView.tag]
    if post.imageLinks.count != 0 {
        let imageLink = post.imageLinks[indexPath.row]

        if imageLink.imageLink != nil {
            let url = URL(string: imageLink.imageLink!)

            cell.imageOfAnimalInCollectionView.sd_setImage(with: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "App-Default"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
            })
        }
else{ 
      cell.imageOfAnimalInCollectionView = "defaultImage"
    }
 }
else{ 
     cell.imageOfAnimalInCollectionView = "defaultImage"
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Reason**
after dequeueing cell `cellectionView` reuses the created cell for all next cells so if you not write an else condition or not use `prepareForReuse` method it will always data of previous cell that is in its cache.