# Swift 3 : tableView duplicating loaded images from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am trying to show a user list with images. Here is the code

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UserListTableViewCell
    let message = messages[indexPath.row]
    cell.message = message
    return cell
}
```

In the UserListTableViewCell file, I am downloading the images ( also using cache) and showing it on the table. But I see that some of the rows have duplicated/repeated image. Upon reloading the duplicates disappear, but its back on vertical scrolling.

This happens : [image]

Here is the UserListTableViewCell file :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UserListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textMessage: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!



var message: Message? {

    didSet {

        if let id = message?.chatPartnerID() {

            let database = Database.database().reference()
            let ref = database.child("Users").child(id)
            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                (snapshot) in

                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {


                        self.username.text = dictionary["username"] as? String

                        if let profileImageUrl = dictionary["image"] as? String, profileImageUrl != "" {
                                                            self.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "blank-user")
                            self.userImage.loadImageFromCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrl)
                            self.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImage.frame.size.width/2
                            self.userImage.clipsToBounds = true

                        } else {

                            self.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "blank-user")
                            self.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImage.frame.size.width/2
                            self.userImage.clipsToBounds = true
                        }

                }



            }, withCancel: nil)
        }


        textMessage.text = (message?.text)! + " " + (message?.chatPartnerID())!

        if let seconds = message?.timestamp?.doubleValue {
            let timestampDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
            timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timestampDate)
        }


        //userImage.image = message?.
    }
} }
```

Image download extension file :

```
extension UIImageView {
func loadImageFromCacheWithUrlString( urlString: String) {

    if urlString != "" {
        self.image = nil

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) {

            self.image = cachedImage as? UIImage
            self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            return
        }


        let url = URL(string : urlString )

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                    self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                }


            })

        }).resume()
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What did you write for the code called at `cell.message`?

Comment: Reuse cell set nil image view

Comment: share your image view code in UserListTableViewCell

Comment: @Larme: shared the code.

Comment: @NazmulHasan: Can you chek now?

Answer (score 7):

Basically you using cell reuse so everytime new reused previous cell so it is reuse previous cell data so your need to clear previous data . You should nil images view download new image or use placeholder image

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UserListTableViewCell
    .   cell.userImage.image = nil
        let message = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.message = message
        return cell
}
```

Update:
[From apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method 
>   dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)
>   . For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in 
>   tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)
>    should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.

so put in your `UserListTableViewCell` class

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
       self.userImage.image() = nil
    // self.userImage.image = nil // above line not working then try this 
}
```

Comment: would you trying this line `cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "")`

Comment: still no luck with that too

Comment: here is another 2 answer posted what about that

Comment: @snowwalker are you sure your image not same at firebase database or image url

Comment: @snowwalker please `userImage`  add subviews to the 
`contentView`
property of the `cell`. When adding subviews, you are responsible for positioning those views and setting their content yourself.

Comment: @snowwalker more check this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell

Comment: This for this, but this too does not help.

Comment: @snowwalker then i am sorry. hope any one help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150069/discussion-between-snowwalker-and-nazmul-hasan).

Answer (score 4):

**An other solution**

You can use `UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!))` to retrieve image from url, but it occupies the main thread, so cache is neccesary.
This solution would not display error image but not good because initialize cause delay.

```
class URLImageRetriever {
    fileprivate static var cache = NSCache<AnyObject,UIImage>()
    static func getImage(from urlString: String) -> UIImage? {
        var image = URLImageRetriever.cache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
        if image == nil {
            do {
                try image = UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!))
                if let image = image {
                    URLImageRetriever.cache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                }
            } catch {

            }
        }
        return image
    }
}
```

**Origin**

Your extension `loadImageFromCacheWithUrlString` might not suitable for this situation.

Let's discuss this situation:

1. Your ImageView `a` requested to present image of `url-a`. Now there is a URLSession `task-a` running.
2. Your UITableViewCell are reused to present another datasource, so your ImageView `a` requested to present image of `url-b`. Now there is a URLSession `task-b` running.
3. `task-b` retrieved picture from `url-b`. Your ImageView `a` now display image from `url-b` perfectly.
4. `tast-a` tetrieved picture later. Your ImageView be set to display image form `url-a`. And make us confused.

You should check what you want to display with your imageview whenever you retrieve picture.

ex:

```
URLImageUtil.loadImageFromCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrl, completion: {
    url, image in
    if self.message.profileImageUrl == url {
        self.userImage.image = image
    }
})
class URLImageUtil {
    static func loadImageFromCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL,_ image: UIImage)->Void) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(
                with: url, completionHandler: {data,response,error in
                    if (data) != nil {
                        if let image = UIImage.init(data: data!) {
                            completion(url, image)
                        } else {
                            print("data not image from url: \(url)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("no data from url: \(url)")
                    }
            })
        } else {
            print("error url: \(urlString)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could get the code to run with .resume(), but still got the image repeating issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it but it's too slow. Any other recommendations on a different way for doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try by this way

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UserListTableViewCell
    cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "blank-user")
    let message = messages[indexPath.row]
    cell.message = message
    return cell
}
```